# Remove nested keys and move value to main dictionary keys

Tags: python, api

I have a problem when I try to merge two dictionaries to fit for doing a post later. For some reason the get seems to be nested and Im not sure how to clean it up. Would be great to get some tips on optimizing the code as well, right now it looks a bit messy.

```
    for network in networks:

            post_dict = {e1:e2 for e1,e2 in network['extattrs'].iteritems() if e1 not in keys }
            pprint (post_dict['Stuff-Name']['value'])

            post_dict['name'] = post_dict.pop('Stuff-Name')
            post_dict['sid'] = post_dict.pop('Stuff-id')

            dict_to_post = merge_two_dicts(post_dict, default_keys)
```

network:

```
{u'_ref': u'ref number',
 u'comment': u'Name of object',
 u'extattrs': {u'Network-Type': {u'value': u'Internal'},
               u'Stuff-Id': {u'value': 110},
               u'Stuff-Name': {u'value': u'Name of object'}},
 u'network': u'Subnet-A',
 u'network_view': u'default'}
```

default_keys:

```
default_keys = {'status':'Active',
                'group':None,
                'site':'City-A',
                'role':'Production',
                'description':None,
                'custom_fields':None,
                'tenant':None}
```

post_dict:

```
{'name': {u'value': u'Name of object'},
 'sid': {u'value': 110}}
```

So what I want to achive is to get rid of the nested keys (within key "name" and "sid" so the key and value pair should be "name: Name of object" and "sid: 110"

The post function is not yet defined.

Comment: Try only posting the code that is necessary to reproduce the issue. `break` the python loop in `for network in networks` and just give us the exact dictionaries of `network`, `post_dict` and `default_keys`

Comment: cleaned up the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, you case is really specific and I would probably go for a easy & dirty solution. First of all have you tried this:

```
post_dict['name'] = (post_dict.pop('Stuff-Name'))['value']
```

Secondly, how about making use of the "filter and renaming" and collapse the indexing there? This is not advisable, but if you are trying to do a lazy work-around it will suffice. I recommend you go with my first suggestion, as I'm pretty confident that it will solve your issue.

Comment: Looks like this solved it! Yes it is very specific so this works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get this first value of any nested dictionary you could use this

```
d = {'custom_fields': None, 'description': None, 'group': None, 'name': 
{'value': 'Name of object'}, 'role': 'Production', 'site': 'City-A', 
'status': 'Active', 'tenant': None, 'sid': {'value': 110}}

for key in d.keys():
  if type(d[key]) == dict:
    d[key] = d[key].popitem()[1]
```

It returns

```
{'custom_fields': None, 'description': None, 'group': None, 'name': 'Name of 
object', 'role': 'Production', 'site': 'City-A', 'status': 'Active', 
'tenant': None, 'sid': 110}
```

I think it's this step that's causing the dictionaries to be nested in the first place

```
post_dict['name'] = post_dict.pop('Stuff-Name')
post_dict['sid'] = post_dict.pop('Stuff-id')
```

You could try popitem()[1] here if you'll only ever need value of that dictionary and not the key.

Comment: Seems to work fine with what you defined. Using it in the code produces another result though:
{'custom_fields': None,
 'description': None,
 'group': None,
 'name': {},
 'role': 'Production',
 'site': 'City-A',
 'status': 'Active',
 'tenant': None,
 'sid': {}}